# Selenium webdriver detect element presense

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am writing a test case using Selenium [PHP Webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver). What i am trying to do is to test if an element exists on the page or not.

I have found [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270092/best-way-to-check-that-element-is-not-present-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156656/how-to-verify-element-present-or-visible-in-selenium-2-selenium-webdriver) for this case, but unfortunately non of them seem to work as expected (With PHP).

```
$element = \WebDriverBy::cssSelector("#not_exists tr > td:first-child");
$found   = $webDriver->findElements($element);
```

Running this snippet throws a `WebDriverCurlException`  instead of `NoSuchElementException` as one would expect.

If you read the [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/php-webdriver/classes/WebDriverSearchContext.html#method_findElements) you will see that in case no elements where found, it should return an empty array which is fine since i could `count()` the results. but this is not the case.

I could wrap this code inside `try - catch` block, but it feels like i am missing something here.